# JOOMLA 3.x How to hide a template after if check

Tags: joomla, hide, default

I'm trying to understand Joomla language and I have this situation:

In a `models/calcoloonline.php` I have this function

```
public function estraivariabili()
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    // Put the result into a variable first, then return it.
    $value = $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__calcolo_imposte")->loadObjectList();

    if ($value != NULL)
    {
        return $value;
    }
    else
    {
        return JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_CALCOLO_IMPOSTE_IMPORTI_NON_DEFINITI'), 'type');
    }
}
```

This works perfectly but I'd like that after check if the return is `NULL` I want to hide display `default.php` and show only the message on `JText`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose, you just return the `$value` from the `model` function and call the function at `view.html.php`'s `display()` function.

At `default.php` file check the availability of the `$value` and show your contents.

For example, you store the data at `view.php.html`. It looks like

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $model = $this->getModel();

    $this->value = $model->estraivariabili();
    return parent::display($tpl);
}
```

And your `default.php` file would be

```
<?php if (!empty($this->value)) { ?>
    <h1>The value is not empty.</h1>
<?php } else {
    // value not found :(
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE'), 'warning');
} ?>
```

Comment: @Sajeeb I'd like to see your wisdom infused into JSE. Please ask that Joomla questions be posted there before you answer them.  That community will have a better chance of growing with the inclusion of your great answers.